# need help programming math between editText

Tags: android, math, int

I need help understanding how to accomplish math between different EditText views. I am not asking someone to write me the code but maybe explain what is involved to get this done.

I wanted to post a picture of this but as a new user I can not. Basicly I have a EditText for the following: Width, Length, Eave Height, Pitch.

I have ID's for all the TextViews I just dont know how to program the behind the scenes math involved to make them work. I do have the equations needed to perform the math just not sure where and how to put them in java.

Basicly I need the user to enter a number in each of the top 4 boxes. I need to use an equation to generate the answer that will be displayed in the "SQFT" box. The user will also input a number in a cost box which will generat a "Total" that needs to be displayed in a separate TextView.

Any help would be appreciated, even if it is to point me in a direction of a tutorial to get me started. Thanks for your help.

Just to show what type of math I need to use, below is the equation I use for excel to calulate.

```
(length+width)*(Eave+1)*2 + (((width/2)/12*Pitch)*(width/2)*2)
```

Comment: No downvote. From you question, it seems that you are a beginner in programming (or may be in Java/Android development). So everything can't be explain to you here. You should read the [official Android docs](http://developer.android.com) and/or [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html). And please read the [StackOverflow FAQs](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) too.

Comment: Thanks, I have looked at the android docs over and over. I wasnt wanting everything explained. All I wanted was to be pointed in a direction to get me started. I admit, I am a beginer with Android and I honestly didnt know beginners couldnt post questions. Sorry about that, although wasnt everyone beginners at some pont?

Comment: Beginner can post questions here. But make sure your question is about a specific programming problem, not some get-me-some-tutorial or how-to-do-this kind of thing. If you don't know about Android, refer its [Hello World.](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html) tutorial. Android is very easy to learn, if you already know Java. If you stuck any where, put your problem here, then community will surely help you.

Comment: I have created hello world. I actually have the main file with six different buttons that open 6 differnt menus using onclicklistener and for a beginner I feel I am picking up the programming for android well, I just seem to be stuck here. I have spent hours trying to find the correct solution but it seems I can not find the right answer.

Comment: We can discuss your problem in chat, as the problem is not clear and without knowing the exact problem we won't be able to provide a good solution. You can invite me whenever you want.
Edit: Ahh.. just realized you need to have certain rep to use the chat. Try to write some of your code and use some picture, so that we can get to know what do you exactly want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you don't know how to extract the numbers entered in the EditTexts, how to actually do the math calculation, how to let the user initiate the calculate or how to present it.

I created a small demo that has 2 EditTexts, and a TextView that displays the sum of the numbers entered. The user does not need to press any buttons to perform the calculation, it is performed automatically every time the user updates the text (I assumed this is what you wanted).

Please note this code is not good code, it uses lots of internal anonymous classes etc but it supposed to demonstrate the mechanics of how to do this.

This is the **main.xml** layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:hint="input a"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:minWidth="60dp"/>
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/b"
        android:hint="input b"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:minWidth="60dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="a+b = " />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/total"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the sample Activity:

```
package com.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SumActivity extends Activity
{
    private int a;
    private int b;
    private TextView totalOutput;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        EditText inputA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.a);
        EditText inputB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.b);
        totalOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total);
        inputA.addTextChangedListener(new TextChangedListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void numberEntered(int number)
            {
                a = number;
                updateTotal();
            }
        });
        inputB.addTextChangedListener(new TextChangedListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void numberEntered(int number)
            {
                b = number;
                updateTotal();
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateTotal()
    {
        int total = a + b; // This is where you apply your function
        totalOutput.setText("" + total); // need to do that otherwise int will
                                            // be treated as res id.
    }

    private abstract class TextChangedListener implements TextWatcher
    {

        public abstract void numberEntered(int number);

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
            String text = s.toString();
            try
            {
                int parsedInt = Integer.parseInt(text);
                numberEntered(parsedInt);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e)
            {
                Log.w(getPackageName(), "Could not parse '" + text + "' as a number", e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Savvas, Thanks. This is a huge help. I will work on this and see what I come up with.

Comment: OK as you probably already know, this worked perfectly. I made a sample program and added two more EditText boxes. I changed the math formula and it worked perfectly. Now I just need to use this in my actual project. This needs to operate the EditText views on different layout than the main layout. On my main layout I have a button that the user clicks and takes them to this layout. Where in the java code do I put this new code. Should it be below everything already in there and start a new public class? I hope this question makes sense. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: if you want to get a better idea what I am talking about you can check out the link...this is where I started before posting on stackoverflow. [link](http://www.tnbforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=150&t=20834&p=125833#p125833)

Comment: I saw your link. You really should read the basics on Android and how to do these things. In short, you need to launch a new Activity when you press the button, not change the layout. Read on activities on Android Developers and you will find your way.

Comment: Savvas, Thanks again for the advice. You probably dont realize but you helped me just by telling me to launch a new Actvity. I now have a new .java file that holds the code you made (w/ me editing it to fit my project w/ 2 more Edittext boxes and changing the id's). I know this seems so basic but thanks again. I will now need to work on changing the "int" to "double" or something that will use 2 decimal points. Then will need to figure out how to use another editText for the cost and multiply it with the result I just made as the total. Work in progress, slowly but surely I am getting closer.